# How do I create dynamic keyboard button telegram bot in C#?

Tags: bots, telegram

How do I create dynamic keyboard button bot telegram in C#?

For example, read value from database and set value to button also count of button equal database row.

Answer (score 0):

you can read data base cell and insert as text [\""+SqlDataReaderTest["YouDataCell"].ToString()+"\"]

```
 string keyboard= "&reply_markup={\"keyboard\":[";
 string temp="";
 while (SqlDataReaderTest.Read())
                {
         temp+=(temp.length==0?"[\"":"],[\"")+SqlDataReaderTest["YouDataCell"].ToString()+"\"]";
                }
keyboard+=temp+"}";
```

remember your (message + keyboard) Length Must be no more than 4000 characters